# SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'114.xxx.xxx.xxx' (using password: YES)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.3

My connection in env file is like this :

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=31.220.56.75
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=chelsea
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=terry
```

When I access my localhost with database server, there is exist error like this :

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'114.xxx.xxx.xxx' (using password: YES)
```

In database server, I try run this : `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'terry' WITH GRANT OPTION;`, there is exist message like this : `Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)`

It looks like it does not work

Is there any people who can help me?

Comment: This is a password error and in mysql, user means 'user'@'hostname'. Please keep this in mind.

Comment: shouldnt HOST be `localhost`?

Comment: @Option, I access server database. No localhost database

Comment: @AdarshGangadharan, I want access database server. No local database. It's different

Comment: You can still use localhost providing the files are on the same server as file manager.

Comment: @Option, What do you mean? I am confused

Comment: Are your files server side? (on the same server as your DB)?

Comment: when you execute the grant, you got the below results, rite?
 Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
what is the 1 warning you got

Comment: @samueltoh From your own console can you do something like `mysql -u root -h 31.220.56.75 -p` and then type your password to check if you are able to login via the password?

Comment: Did you flush privileges after granting?

Comment: @prateekkathal, there is exist message like this : `bash: mysql: command not found`. because i'm using windows

Comment: @prateekkathal, https://postimg.org/image/rc0mdec5l/

Comment: @AdarshGangadharan, `Warning Code : 1287
Using GRANT statement to modify existing user's properties other than privileges is deprecated and will be removed in future release. Use ALTER USER statement for this operation.`

Comment: @Option, yes, it's right

Comment: @JayBlanchard, yes, but it's not working

Comment: @samueltoh The problem is definitely with the password. The privileges for the database comes after the part where you have already logged in...

Answer (score 0):

Verify in your my.cnf to comment this line

```
bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

and in mysql console

```
flush privileges;
```

**Finally restart the mysql server.**